# How to design front end architecture for handling multiple brands in aem?

Tags: javascript, webpack, architecture, frontend, aem

For aem projects, if I want to publish sites of different brands with same codebase, if there is any robust loosely coupled front end architecture, please suggest.e.g for site X we should have different theming, for Y different theming and for z different theming for components.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your designs in /etc/designs/{common-library-folder} and assign a property category="xyz"

Now in your pages (for different brand) you can include the designs via  tag by specifing the category name.

This will help in grouping and reusability of the designs.

Comment: Thanks.I will check and confirm